# Java program that separates number from a credit card and multiplies each by 2

Tags: java

I'm trying to separate digits from a number and multiply each one by 2 and then cocatenating the results. The result ends up being one digit less.

My program first asks for a credit card number and then saves every other digit starting with the number's second to last digit into a variable. It's supossed to multiply each of this lasts number digits by 2. By adding a print in the for loop, it starts correctly but it deletes a digit in the 4th iteration.

I've tried adding a conditional to check if the last number was a 0 so it doesn't delete but the program completely breaks. This is my code:

```
package credit;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Integer;

public class Credit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Pedir al usuario un número de tarjeta
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        long tarjeta;
        int result = 0;
        System.out.print("Por favor, introduce tu número de tarjeta >> ");
        tarjeta = scanner.nextLong();
        
        // Convertimos long a string
        String string_number = tarjeta+"";
        String string_numbershort = "";
        
        System.out.println(tarjeta);
        System.out.println(string_number);
        
        for (int i = string_number.length() - 2; i >= 0; i = i - 2) {
            // Sacamos digitos de dos en dos empezando por el penultimo
            System.out.print(string_number.charAt(i));
            string_numbershort = string_numbershort + string_number.charAt(i);
            
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < string_numbershort.length(); i++) {
            // Equivalente a funcion atoi() en c
            result = result * 10 + (string_numbershort.charAt(i) - '0') * 2;
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And the results in my terminal:

```
Por favor, introduce tu número de tarjeta >> 4003600000000014
4003600000000014
4003600000000014
100006042
20
200
2000
20000 // This the 0 that gets deleted!!
200012
2000120
20001208
```

The result I'm expecting to be printed is 200001208 not 20001208.

Comment: In Java snake_case is not used, but camelCase. There is no need to define `long tarjeta`, better do that when initializing it: `long tarjeta = scanner.nextLong();`. It is considered bad style to convert numbers to strings as in `String string_number = tarjeta+"";` - better use `Integer.toString(tarjeta)` or `String.valueOf(tarjeta)`. You are often appending strings, especially in the first for-loop - better use a `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this line of your code:

```java
result = result * 10 + (string_numbershort.charAt(i) - '0') * 2;
```

if `(string_numbershort.charAt(i) - '0') * 2` is greater than 10, then you want to multiply `result` by 100 and not by 10, i.e.

```java
int temp = (string_numbershort.charAt(i) - '0') * 2;
if (temp > 10) {
    result = result * 100 + temp;
}
else {
    result = result * 10 + temp;
}
```

Here is your program (with my corrections as described above):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Credit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Pedir al usuario un número de tarjeta
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        long tarjeta;
        int result = 0;
        System.out.print("Por favor, introduce tu número de tarjeta >> ");
        tarjeta = scanner.nextLong();
        
        // Convertimos long a string
        String string_number = tarjeta+"";
        String string_numbershort = "";
        
        System.out.println(tarjeta);
        System.out.println(string_number);
        for (int i = string_number.length() - 2; i >= 0; i = i - 2) {
            // Sacamos digitos de dos en dos empezando por el penultimo
            System.out.print(string_number.charAt(i));
            string_numbershort = string_numbershort + string_number.charAt(i);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < string_numbershort.length(); i++) {
            // Equivalente a funcion atoi() en c
            int additive = (string_numbershort.charAt(i) - '0') * 2;
            int multiplier = additive > 10 ? 100 : 10;
            result = result * multiplier + additive;
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output of running the above code using your sample credit card number, i.e. 4003600000000014

```
Por favor, introduce tu número de tarjeta >> 4003600000000014
4003600000000014
4003600000000014
100006042
20
200
2000
20000
2000012
20000120
200001208
```

Of-course, no need for all the conversions from `long` (or `int`) to `String` (and vice-versa). You can directly manipulate the number entered (via method `nextLong` in class `Scanner`) using arithmetic operations only, as demonstrated in the below code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Credit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Card number: ");
        long number = scanner.nextLong();
        long result = 0;
        long multiplier;
        while (number > 0) {
            number /= 10;
            long digit = number % 10;
            long amount = digit * 2;
            multiplier = amount > 10 ? 100 : 10;
            result *= multiplier;
            result += amount;
            number /= 10;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```